# How to replace part of a string in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

On my field `phone` I have like these values:

```
Phone: 1234567
```

What I want to achieve is to replace the `Phone:` (there is a space after `:` so I can be only with the number. I tried the following without luck

```
SELECT REPLACE( phone,  'Phone: ',  '' ) 
FROM EVENTS
```

Comment: I have to ask why in column called `phone` would you save the data with text in there anyway?

Comment: @Dale you have a nice question there, however I had to have text in there for a reason.

Comment: Is Phone: on all results or just some?

Comment: @Kaoukkos That query works for me. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Try to remove the leading space from the data  by using LTRIM.

Answer (score 1):

I usually rename the returned value as a new field, in this case `phone_replaced`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(`phone`, 'Phone: ', '') as `phone_replaced` FROM `events`
```

But you can also keep the current name `phone`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(`phone`, 'Phone: ', '') as `phone` FROM `events`
```

As long as you alias it using `as`.

Comment: +1 You don't actually have to rename it, but you must alias it at least or it's actually returned as `REPLACE(column, 'blah: ', '')` and that's just a nightmare to type

Comment: True, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works:

```
create table T (data char(40));
insert into T values
 ('Phone: 1235678'),
 ('Tel: 0505074455'),
 ('Phone: 0418192244');

select REPLACE(data, 'Phone: ','') from T;
```

Result:

```
REPLACE(DATA, 'PHONE: ','')
1235678
Tel: 05-05-07-44-55
0418192244
```

If you only want "matching" lines, you should add a relevant where clause:

```
select REPLACE(data, 'Phone: ','') from T
  where data LIKE 'Phone: %';
```

If you really want *numbers* you might use [`CAST ... as DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
select CAST(REPLACE(data, 'Phone: ','') as DECIMAL) from T
  where data LIKE 'Phone: %';
```

If you have to deal with case, try normalizing the string using `LOWER`:

```
select CAST(REPLACE(LOWER(data), 'phone: ','') as DECIMAL) from T
  where LOWER(data) LIKE 'phone: %';
```

That later would not perform well because MySQL won't be able to use the potential index on `data` I think. If you need, you should use case insensitive collation for the `data`column. But that's an other story...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38218d/7

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using the PHP. Use it:

```
$phone = "Phone: 1234567"
$arr = explode(" ",$phone);
$phone = $arr[1];
```

Or use the SQL syntax:

```
SELECT REPLACE("Phone: 1234567",  'Phone: ',  '' ) FROM EVENTS
```

Comment: This will work for only one phone number, however I have numerous rows with phones

Comment: @Kaoukkos I have given the other solution also.

Answer (score 0):

You try :-

```
SELECT LTRIM(phone) FROM EVENTS;
```

Read more about [LTRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim).

For Replaceing :-

```
SELECT REPLACE(phone,phone,LTRIM(phone)) FROM EVENTS;
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that names are case sensitive here so `Phone:` is not same as `phone:`

```
     SELECT case when phone like 'phone%' then REPLACE( phone,  'phone: ',  '' ) 
                 when phone like 'Phone%' then REPLACE( phone,  'Phone: ',  '' )
            end as Phone_number
     FROM EVENTS
```